# Uniqueness in Weierstraß p-adic preparation theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

I have given the Weierstraß p-adic preparation theorem. It is stated as follows: Let $f=a_0 + a_1T + ... \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ for a prime $p$ such that $p \mid a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ and $p\not\mid a_n$. Then there exists a unique unit $U\in\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]^*$ and a distinguished polynomial P of degree $n$, i.e. $P= b_0 + b_1 T + ... + b_{n-1}T^{n-1}+T^n$ with $p\mid b_0,...,b_{n-1}$ such that $f=PU$.

The existence is clear to me but the uniqueness not. Both supposedly follow from a prior theorem, division with rest. It is stated as follows: 
Let $f=a_0 + a_1T + ... \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ for a prime $p$ such that $p \mid a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ and $p\not\mid a_n$. Then, for all $g\in\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ there is a unique expression $$ g = qf + r $$ with $ q \in \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ and $ r $ a polynomial of degree $ \deg(r) \le n-1 $.

The uniqueness statement that I require is a rather strong one. I need that if $f=PU$ as in the first theorem and also $f=P'U'$ with $U'$ a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ and $P'$ a polynomial, then $P=P'$ and $U=U'$. My problem is that P' might have a different degree than $P$, in which case I do not see how to apply division with rest.

I need this strong uniquement because I would like to conclude from this theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ is a UFD.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $P'=PU$ with $U$ a unit, go modulo $p$ to get an equation $T^n=T^mu$ where $u$ is $U$ modulo $p$. This is an equation in $\mathbb{F}_p[[T]]$ and $u$ is a unit in this ring. Can you prove now that $m=n$?

Comment: It was not clear to me that OP intended for $P'$ to be a monic polynomial with nonleading coefficients divisible by $p$. Of course this stronger assertion of uniqueness, with $P'$ even required to be a monic polynomial, is never valid.  Counterexamples like $f = (T + b_0)\frac{1}{T+1} = (T^2 + (b_0 + 1)T  + b_0) \frac{1}{(T+1)^2}$ abound.

Answer (score 1):

As @BadamBaplan says, your desired uniqueness does not hold. Consider, for instance, the polynomial $f=p+X^n+pX^{n+1}$. Then we have the factorization $U'=1$, $P'=f$, and the Weierstraß factorization $f=UP$, where indeed, $P$ and $U$ are given to you already by Hensel’s Lemma. If I understand your question aright, the factorization $f=U'P'$ satisfies your criteria.

Comment: What does "your criteria" in the last sentence mean? Is there some other uniqueness statement that holds for the factorization $U'P'$?

Comment: Oh, @aleph_two, “your criteria” refers to the paragraph in OP’s question that starts, “The uniqueness statement that I require…”.

Comment: Thank you! So that sentence just means that your first factorization actually provides a counterexample.

Comment: Precisely, @aleph_two.